# Batch Then was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this code...

```
echo ---- Beginning downloads ----

rem for every plugin with var %%s being the number of the plugin
for /l %%s in (1,1,!plugin_counter!) do (
    echo.
    set /a dl=1
    rem If it's a zip file
    if defined zip_plugin_name[%%s] (
        set zip_plugin_name_=!zip_plugin_name[%%s]!
        set plugin_name_=!zip_plugin_name_!.zip
    rem Otherwise, if it isn't a zip file, we can assume it's a jar because, for now, only .zip's and .jar's are downloaded.
    ) else (
        set plugin_name_=!plugin_name[%%s]!.jar
    )
    set plugin_URL_index_=!plugin_URL_index[%%s]!
    set plugin_full_name=!plugin_URL_index_! / !plugin_name_!
    if defined plugin_disabled_reason[%%s] (
        echo Not downloading !plugin_full_name!. Reason:
        echo !plugin_disabled_reason[%%s]!
        echo Not downloading !plugin_full_name!. Reason:>> %LOGFILE_NAME%
        echo !plugin_disabled_reason[%%s]!>> %LOGFILE_NAME%
        set /a dl=0
    )
    if /i !dl!==1 (
        echo Downloading !plugin_full_name! ...
    )
    rem Try downloading 3 times.
    for /l %%t in (1,1,3) do (
        if /i !dl!==1 (
            if defined alt_url[%%s] (
                dl.vbs "!alt_url[%%s]!" "%OUTPUT_DIR%\!plugin_name_!"
            ) else (
                dl.vbs "https://api.bukget.org/3/plugins/bukkit/!plugin_URL_index_!/%type%/download" "%OUTPUT_DIR%\!plugin_name_!"
            )
            if exist "%OUTPUT_DIR%\!plugin_name_!" (
                set /a dl=0
            ) else (
                rem It doesn't technically retry the third time it would say this.
                if not %%t==3 (
                    echo Error downloading !plugin_full_name!; retrying...
                    echo Error downloading !plugin_full_name!; retrying...>> %LOGFILE_NAME%
                )
            )
            rem If it's a zip
            if defined zip_plugin_name[%%s] (
                rem Try unzipping 3 times
                for /l %%k in (1,1,3) do (
                    if not exist %OUTPUT_DIR%\!plugin_name[%%s]! (
                        echo Unzipping...
                        echo !plugin_full_name! was zipped; unzipping...>> %LOGFILE_NAME%

                        md %zip_temp_dir%

                        rem Unzip the plugin to a temporary directory
                        Call :UnZipFile "%cd%\%zip_temp_dir%\" "%cd%\%OUTPUT_DIR%\!zip_plugin_name_!"

                        :UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
                        >%zip_vbs_name%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                        >>%zip_vbs_name% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
                        >>%zip_vbs_name% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
                        >>%zip_vbs_name% echo End If
                        >>%zip_vbs_name% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        >>%zip_vbs_name% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
                        >>%zip_vbs_name% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
                        >>%zip_vbs_name% echo Set fso = Nothing
                        >>%zip_vbs_name% echo Set objShell = Nothing
                        cscript //nologo %zip_vbs_name%
                        del /f /q %zip_vbs_name%

                        move "%zip_temp_dir%\!zip_plugin_name_!" "%OUTPUT_DIR%\"

                        rem Delete the temporary folder
                        rd /s /q %zip_temp_dir%
                    )
                )
                echo Unzipped.
                echo Unzipped successfully.>> %OUTPUT_DIR%
            )
            rem Delete the old plugin zip file
            del /f /q %OUTPUT_DIR%\!plugin_name_!
        )
    )
    if not exist "%OUTPUT_DIR%\!plugin_name_!" (
        if /i !dl!==1 (
            echo Couldn't download !plugin_full_name!.
            echo Couldn't download !plugin_full_name!.>>%LOGFILE_NAME%
        )
    ) else (
        echo Successfully downloaded !plugin_full_name!.>>%LOGFILE_NAME%
        echo Finished; successful download.
    )
    echo.>>%LOGFILE_NAME%
)
```

...which, frankly, was ripped out of my program and is out of context.

This is beacuse I feel that this is a syntax error and doesn't *really* need context -- **If it does, let me know.**

A couple of notes:

- Yes, I have `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` on.
- The error it's producing is as shown below:

[image: Error]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) all `)` closing parentheses if should be used literally in `echo` command.

Proof (from command prompt):

```
==>(echo x)
x

==>(echo x(y))
) was unexpected at this time.

==>(echo x(y^))
x(y)
```

Another escaping approach (note that `cmd /V:ON` enables delayed expansion for command line):

```
==>cmd /V:ON
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

==>set "line=x(y)"

==>(echo !line!)
x(y)
```

Next `.bat` code snippet shows some *useful* escaping practice for batch scripting. Maybe not exhaustive, maybe not all necessary:

```
@ECHO %%  - Percentage Sign: are used to mark three of the four variable types
@ECHO ^^  - Caret: general escape character in batch ^(and in CLI as well^)
  @setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
@ECHO ^!  - Exclamation Mark ^(disabledelayedexpansion^) ^!var^!
  @endlocal
  @setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@ECHO ^^!  - Exclamation Mark  ^(enabledelayedexpansion^) ^^!var^^! ^(double the caret^)
  @endlocal
@ECHO ^&  - Single Ampersand: used as a command separator
@ECHO ^&^& - Double Ampersand: conditional command separator ^(if %%errorlevel%% EQU 0^)
@ECHO ^|^| - Double Pipe: conditional command separator      ^(if %%errorlevel%% GTR 0^)
@ECHO ^(^) - Parentheses: used to make "code blocks" of grouped commands
@ECHO ^|  - Single Pipe: redirects the std. output of one command
@ECHO                   into the std. input of another
@ECHO ^>  - Single Greater Than: redirects output to either a file or file like device
@ECHO ^>^> - Double Greater than: output will be added to the very end of the file
@ECHO ^<  - Less Than: redirect the contents of a file to the std.input of a command
@echo ^"  - Double Quote: surrounding a string in double quotes escapes
@echo                    all of the characters contained within it
@echo ^   - Space character: if a^^ b==a^^ b @echo match ^(use one caret only^) 
@echo ^@  - At Symbol: be less verbose; e.g. @x.bat should be launched 
@echo                                   by ^^@x.bat ^(use one caret only^)
@echo ^~  - Tilde: Parameter Expansion as in Call subroutines, FOR loops etc.
@echo ^:^: - Double Colon: alternative to "rem" for comments outside of code blocks
@echo ^*  - Asterisk: wildcard matches any number or any characters
@echo ^?  - Question Mark: matches any single character
@echo ^.  - Single dot: represents the current directory
@echo ^.^. - Double dot: represents the parent directory of the current directory
@echo ^\  - Backslash: represent the root directory of a drive dir ^\
@echo ^NUL ^(File like device^): ^NUL is like a bottomless pit
@echo ^CON ^(File like device^): ^CON represents the console
```

Comment: Should opening parens not also be escaped? And thank you! I will try this.

Comment: If I escape both `(` and `)`, the closing parens on my created VBS will not be made. If I only escape `)`, the created file is: `Set fso = Nothing`
`Set objShell = Nothing`

Comment: Actually, it seems that, either way, that two-liner is created.

Comment: This isn't working for me, as I have explained in my earlier comments. Can you help in any way?

Comment: It's another issue. Read [CALL a subroutine (:label)](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) Move all the `:UnZipFile` subroutine to the end of your script combining with `goto :eof` as explained in  example there: see how the `:sub_display` procedure is defined and called

Comment: OK, well, I decided to just have it as an external file, anyway -- no file creation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.